# Allow a very limited set of (not reduntant) tags for answers to improve them

Tags: feature-request, tags, answers

Here is an example to explain it:

If we look at the **sql** tag, then there are a lot of questions that have many possible answers. They could be tagged as follows:

**one-time-operation**: Typically answers that are not very performant but easy to understand. Also answers that tend to follow in the next category.

**generalized**: Will work on all major dbms: oracle, postgres, mysql, db2 ... to be defined.

Or for all **programming languages** we could have two tags: **optimized-readability** and **optimized-performance** and maybe more to show more clearly what the goal of the answer is.

**Why?** Depending on what the goal is the answers can be very different, this would make it easier to find what you are looking for and gives hints to beginners.

You may say this should be decided on the question-level, but often it isn't done and you can only use 5 tags. It seems silly to ask the same question twice, e.g. once with the goal of improved readability and once with improved performance. It should also be considered that the search engines likely prefer one of the questions and then only this one is found in the first hits, so splitting it doesn't seem to be wise.

Comment: I actually hate those non self contained questions trying to narrow their scope just with additional tagging. Most (new) OPs do it wrong, and leave way to broad (specialized) and unanswerable questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes you are right, I just think it would be silly to split the old questions, but in the future hopefully motivate people to use those tags in questions too. But as it is right now this is pretty low priority I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any official tagging system to support this information.  The author can simply state all of this information in their answer if they feel that it's important for the reader to understand it.

There shouldn't be so many answers to any given question that you're looking at that you'd need some sort of automated filtering/searching tool that uses tags in order to find answers that you're interested in.  People looking for a solution to a problem should generally only have a few to choose between, and votes are already a great signal as to what order they should look at each of the answers in.

Comment: That's the thing, assuming many answers don't have this information, it is much more easier if someone can just tag then instead of having to write text which might get refused etc.

Comment: @maraca I would expect it to be generally apparent, or irrelevant, in the vast majority of cases.  In those cases where it's important and unclear, the author can make it clear.  If you feel that there is important information missing from the answer, such as that it's generalized, highly specific, not performant, etc., you can provide that information in comments.

Comment: You understand where I'm getting at, those could be tags, and I see your point on the other hand comments can just get burried. It's absolutely no need, I just think it would be a nice feature, because it might motivate people to also use the tags in questions, what makes them immediately clearer.

Comment: @maraca Given that the information is very rarely relevant, is typically very apparent when it is relevant, and it's easy enough to convey the information without any special tools in those rare cases where it is both important and relevant, no, I see no need for there to be tags.  And that's not even *starting* to bring up the controversy side.  People won't always agree on whether an answer is performant, general, readable, etc.

Comment: Yes I see, you are right I wouldn't bother with it either the reward is too small. But if implementing it would only take 10s, it might be worth considering it... well it isn't doable in 10s so I accept your answer.